# AnKo SQLite : populate listview asynchronously from database?

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, android-cursorloader, anko

I'm trying to translate my app from Java to Kotlin.
I'm managing database with AnKo SQLite

All is OK except listviews with CursorLoaders : I can't find how to replace CursorLoader while using AnKo SQLite.
(and same problem with expandableListViews)

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is my solution... I don't know if it is the best :

1. create a new kotlin class "MyCursorLoader" that extends CursorLoader
2. set the primary constructor like this :

   `class MyCursorLoader( 
       mContext: Context,
       val mTableName: String,
       var mProjection: Array<String>? = null,
       var mSelection: String = "1",
       var mSelectionArgs: Array<String> = emptyArray(),
       var mGroupBy: String = MySqlHelper.ID,
       var mHaving: String = "",
       var mSortOrder: String = "${MySqlHelper.ID} ASC",
       var mLimit: String = "",
       var mDistinct: Boolean = true
   ): CursorLoader(mContext) {
   val mObserver: Loader<Cursor>.ForceLoadContentObserver = Loader<Cursor>(mContext).ForceLoadContentObserver()
   var mCancellationSignal: CancellationSignal? = null`
3. override the OnLoadInBackground method with te same code than built-in one, just replacing the `val cursor = ContentResolverCompat.query(...` line with :

   ```
   val cursor = MySqlHelper.instance.readableDatabase.query(
       mDistinct, mTableName, mProjection, mSelection, mSelectionArgs, mGroupBy, mHaving, mSortOrder, mLimit, mCancellationSignal)
   ```

So no need to recreate a dataprovider in manifest, no need to deal with Uri's... I can use MyCursorLoader exactly like built-in CursorLoader, calling it like this :

```
    override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor> {
        when (id) {
            DAY_HEADER_LOADER ->
                return MyCursorLoader(mContext, TABLE_EVENTS, arrayOf(ID, DAY), mGroupBy = DAY, mSortOrder = "$DAY  DESC")
        ...
        }
    }
```

Let me know if ther is a better solution.

Hope that can help.